# Covariant derivative do Carmo help clarification concept

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $\nabla$ be a connection compatible with the metric. Then for any vector fields $V,W$ along the smooth curve $c:I\rightarrow M$ , we have

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle V, W\rangle =\langle \frac{DV}{dt},W\rangle+ \langle V, \frac{DW}{dt}\rangle$

However my question is: Why does $\frac{d}{dt} \langle V, W \rangle$ make sense?

$V$ and $W$ are vector fields along a curve, so I suppose $\langle V, W\rangle$ is viewed as a map $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , where $\langle V,W \rangle(t)=\langle V_t, W_t \rangle$ . But how do we show that it is smooth?  Also compatibility of the metric is defined on smooth vector fields.

Comment: This is indeed a good question. My suggestion for now is to write everything in local coordinates and verify that it all works.

Comment: Show that $g$ is a smooth metric is equivalent to the condition for that all pairs of vector fields $X, Y$ on $M$, the mapping $p\mapsto g_p(X,Y), p\in M$, is smooth.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but we're dealing with vector fields along a curve, not vector fields and vector fields along curves aren't necessarily extendable to smooth vector fields

Comment: True, but it is the same story: vector fields along a curve are sections of the pull-back bundle $E=(c^*(TM)\to I)$. Show that the pull-back of $g$ is a smooth metric on $E$ and that for any two sections $X, Y$ of $E$, hence, the function $<X,Y>$ on $I$ is smooth.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I still don't know much about pullback bundles, could you write an answer without using pullback bundles, please?

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a smooth manifold then $TM$ also has a natural smooth structure, hence, does $E=TM\times TM$. The projection $\pi: TM\to M$ defines a smooth map
$$
\pi\times \pi: E\to M^2. 
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that the preimage of the diagonal under $\pi\times \pi$ is a smooth submanifold $A$ in $E$.  Explicitly:
$$
A=\{(u,v)\in TM\times TM: \pi(u)=\pi(v)\},
$$
i.e. $A$ consists of pairs of vectors in the same tangent space $T_pM$, $p\in M$.

A Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ is a smooth function $g: A\to {\mathbb R}$ (satisfying further linearity conditions which are irrelevant for us). Given a curve $c: I\to M$, a vector field $X$ along $c$ is a smooth map $X: I\to TM$ such that $\pi\circ X=c$. A pair of such vector fields $X, Y$ defines a smooth map $P: I\to A$. Hence, the composition of two smooth maps $g\circ P$ is again smooth. This composition is nothing but the function
$$
t\mapsto g(X,Y)(t), t\in I. 
$$

Comment: The second paragraph is the answer to the original question, but what is the relevance of the first paragraph?

Comment: @Deane: The role of the first paragraph is to define $A$ and to state that it is a smooth manifold.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify how a Riemannian metric is a smooth function $g:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @monoidaltransform: By the definition of a Riemannian metric: It is supposed to be smooth and its inputs are vectors in the same tangent space.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the story without using pullback bundles: A vector field $V$ along the curve $c: I \rightarrow M$ is defined to be a smooth map $V: I \rightarrow T_*M$, where $V(t) \in T_{c(t)}M$. In local coordinates, the covariant derivative of $V = V^k\partial_k$ along $c$ is defined to be
$$
\frac{DV}{dt} = \left(\frac{dV^i}{dt} + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{c}^j V^k\right)\partial_i, $$
where $\dot{c}$ is the derivative of $c$ and $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ are the Christoffel symbols. You can check that this definition is co-ordinate-independent and satisfies all the expected properties.

If you want the story using pullback bundles, see, for example, [https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/pullback.pdf](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eyangd/papers/pullback.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on why that means the derivative I mentioned makes sense please? I still don't quite get it.

Comment: If, by definition, $V$ and $W$ are smooth maps from $I$ to $T_*M$ and the Riemannian metric is assumed to be smooth, then the function $t \mapsto \langle V(t),W(t)\rangle$ is smooth and can be differentiated. Note that this and the definition of $\frac{DV}{dt}$ work, even if the velocity of $c$ vanishes anywhere along $I$.

Comment: But smoothness of the Riemannian metric is defined by taking vector fields, so if $X,Y$ are smooth on $M$, $g(X,Y):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by $g(X,Y)(p)=g(X_p,Y_p)$ is smooth

Comment: The definition of smoothness of the metric does not need to refer to vector fields. The Riemannian metric is a function $g: T_*M \times T_*M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The metric is smooth, if this function is smooth. Another explanation is given in @MosheKohan's answer.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this clarifies it. @Deane It's an if and only if, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "if and only if". If you mean the two different definitions of a smooth metric, my recommendation is to use only mine and view the smooth vector field statement as a consequence. They're probably equivalent, but I don't think the converse is ever useful.

Comment: Just to be clear, your definition is  that the metric tensor is a smooth function $g:TM\times TM \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that....?

Comment: Oops. Good question. My explanation of a smooth metric is incorrect. You should use @MoisheKohan's.

Comment: A more mundane way to define smoothness of the metric is to say that in local coordinates $x = (x^1, \dots, x^n)$, the metric is $g = g_{ij}(x)\,dx^i\,dx^j$, where  $g_{ij}(x)$ are smooth functions of $x \in M$.

Comment: Another way is to define the bundle $S^2T^*M$ of symmetric $2$-tensors and observe that a metric is a section of this bundle and it's smooth if the section is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $\langle V,W \rangle: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  given by $\langle V,W \rangle (t)=\langle V_t,W_t \rangle_{c(t)}$ is indeed smooth.

Let $M$ be your manifold.
Let $t\in I$, So, $c(t)\in M$. Choose a frame $(U,e_1,.....,e_n)$ of $c(t)$ such that $\{$ $e_1,.....,e_n$ $\}$ forms an orthonormal local frame $U\rightarrow TM$ (Note $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle$  is smooth on $U$ for each $i,j$). Therefore $V_t=V^j(t)e_j$ and $W=W^k(t)e_k$ for smooth functions $V^j$ and $W^k$ on $I$. Hence, $\langle V_t , W_t\rangle= \sum_iV^i(t)W^i(t)$.